# можно ли использовать бесплатный Assetstore пак в коммерческом проекте?

Tags: unity3d

Работаю по договору хочу закачать паки по типу LeanTween, если  буду использовать только классы. Смогут ли они как нибудь отследить что я использовал пак или же например сейчас он бесплатный а его сделают платным а он уже в коммерческом проекте. Будет и у меня какая нибудь лицензия? даже если я передал проект другому лицу или у него?

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите, там у каждого пака есть тип лицензии. Посмотрите относительно вашего. Правда там будет много текста, но раз коммерческое использование, то стоит потратить время на перевод.

А вообще на форме Unity пишут, что можно использовать бесплатные ассеты даже в коммерческих проектах.

Comment: Всего есть два типа расширенния? они все одинаковые в описании то есть "Актив расширения" всегда одно и тоже описание. Или надо читать на сайтах компании которой используешь асет на коммерческое использование?

Comment: @СергейХарланов, нет, не надо читать на сайте. На AssetsStore действует привилегия на права. То есть, вы оперируете правами, которые указаны на AssetsStore. О них (fee) я указал выше. Информацию взял также с форумов