# Лицензия unity asset store

Tags: unity3d, assets

Подскажите, купил паки с ассет стор, после, заметил что иконки и т. д. используются в другой игре, подскажите, если я их использую в коммерческой игре это допустимо? вот ссылка https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/2d/gui/classic-rpg-gui-160253

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1251861/191482

Comment: я читал лицензию... но там так размыто... или перевод не качественный, толком ничего не понял и там 2ве лицензии я выбрал ту, что дешевле... вот и вопрос возник

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я вижу там есть 2 варианта покупки - Single entity и Multi Entity.

Если кликнуть на "see details" то мы можем прчесть что первая лицензия означает что ассет можешь использовать только на одно юридическое лицо, второй тип лицензии - на много юридических лиц.

Фактически это означает "имеешь подрядчиков своего проэкта - купи больше лицензий, работаешь сам - покупай лишь одну".

Т.к. ты вряд ли будешь ассет распостранять на другие юридические лица ты правильно сделал что купил более дешевую лицензию.

Было бы странно продавать ассет запрещая использовать в коммерческих целях. Они именно и продаются что бы ты их мог использовать в коммерческих целях.

Comment: Ну т.е. получается что один и тот же ассет могут встретиться во многих играх... как то не правильно я считаю... но спасибо за ответ.

Comment: это не неправильно, это логично. Если бы его можно было встретить только в одной игре - он бы стоял не 9 долларов, а несколько тысяч. Там много человекочасов работы. Хочешь индивидуальный ассет - найми художника и пусть делает тебе работу с нуля и плати ему зарплату. Будет тебе твой личный ассет под твою личную игру.